# tsql join best practices advice

Tags: t-sql

First of all, English it's not my first language, feel free to edit my question and I'm sorry for any mistakes that can offend you or not being so clear exposing the problem.

I have a few sql queries with lots of joins, these joins are based on clustered index (no worries about that). Some of the joins are used only to respect normalization and because is intuitive to maintenance, but sometimes it's possible to skip some of then. It's not clear to me what to do about these joins in terms of best practices.

Edit:

A simple example:

```
select *
from things
join things_categories on
    things_categories.id_thing = things.id_thing
join categories on
    categories.id_category = things_categories.id_category
join categories_properties on
    categories_properties.id_category = categories.id_category
where
    categories_properties.bo_default = 1
```

But it's possible to do:

```
select *
from things
join things_categories on
    things_categories.id_thing = things.id_thing
join categories_properties on
    categories_properties.id_category = things_categories.id_category
where
    categories_properties.bo_default = 1
```

The second join it's not necessary (I do have integrity at database level), it's there only because makes the code more intuitive and respect the database normalization. I'm not sure if I should follow the smallest possible and efficient path or leave unnecessary joins to respect normalization and make the code more intuitive.

Any tips?

All the best.

Comment: This isn't a real question imho, so I doubt you get any useful answers.

Comment: I don't agree with you, but thank you anyway.

Comment: what's the issue you are facing? meaning, what must change and why?

Comment: I agree with @YvesR.  You need to be more specific.  This question as it's currently worded won't get anything more than a vague answer which may or may not answer your question.  I recommend you create a concrete example to represent your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It deppends, wheter you've or not integrity already.**

In one hand, if the `categories_properties table` has a `foreign key` in the `id_category column`, then the integrity exists and you don't need to make the `join` with the `categories table`.

On the other hand, if the integrity might not exist (i.e.: there are `id_categories` in `categories_properties table` that are not defined in `categories table`), then you should make the `join`.

Comment: The integrity exists (database level). But sometimes skipping these steps makes the code so hard to read that I tend to put the unnecessary steps anyways.

Comment: Then it's performance (it doesn't affect that much) vs readability.

Comment: Yeh, but consider I'm using the unncessary steps over clustered keys. Is it that bad to performance?

Comment: It deppends on the number of rows in categories but I guess it's not a big deal! :D

Comment: Yeh, there are less than 100 categories. And by the way, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The join:

```
join categories on
    categories.id_category = things_categories.id_category
```

is very necessary, since the `categories` table is used in the next join:

```
join categories_properties on
    categories_properties.id_category = categories.id_category
```

So it's definitely required, if it's not already defined, as SQL requires for you to establish the links it needs to index and join one to the next.

What is however very painful, is the `select *`.
You don't need all that info, since * will bring all data from all tables.

Perhaps you could specify what you need from each table or, at worst, use things.* to specify all columns of a specific table.

Comment: The * is used only because it's a sample. I can make the next join skipping the categories table because I already have the id_category I need to join the other table.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need a join do not use it. You are taking a totally unneeded performance hit. Don't force the database to do work it doesn't need to do because you think it looks more comlete, you should consider performance ahead of readability in a query. After all once you start writing performant SQl code, it will become more readable to you. However, make sure you actually don't need it before eliminating it by making sure both versions of the query return the same result set.